# NestedScrollView not scrolling to the bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-nestedscrollview

This layout is part of my learning process. So please don't judge the use of `textview` for displaying data.

The problem is i am not able to scroll the entire data in the bottom `textview`. Always 2 sets of data is left behind.
If i have 8 sets,the `scrollview` will show up to 6 sets. If i have 4 set it will show 2 sets and wont scroll at all. What's the problem with my `scrollview`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".FireStoreNotes">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/title" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/description" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout3"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout2">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_priority"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/priority"
        android:inputType="number" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/button_add"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:text="@string/add_notes"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout3" />

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/button_load"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:text="@string/load_notes"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_add" />

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_load">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_loadData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

 </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is how my layout looks.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edit ConstraintLayout root `layout_height` (`match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`)

For `NestedScrollView` :

- Replace `layout_width`and `layout_height` values by `0dp`for applying constraints.
- Add a bottom constraint with `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`